# Как использовать соединение node.js с mysql в коде, на который ссылается html файле?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть маленький тестовый код на js и база данных mysql, код делает простую выборку из базы. При запуске кода через node он работает, но если вписать его в html файл, то выдает ошибку о не определенности функции connection. Как мне сделать так, чтобы html файл мог использовать функции и связи из Node.js?

Comment: Никак, node js - серверный язык, javascript - клиентский, это разные языки хоть визуально и схожи.

Comment: посылать запрос с клиента на node сделать "что-то"